# aufzuhören or aufhören?

Tags: infinitive

I was reading *"Der kleine Prinz"* when I found

> ... die grossen Leute haben mir geraten, mit den Zeichnungen von offenen oder geschlossenen Riesenschlangen **aufzuhören** ...

Well, so I go seek for the meaning of *"aufzuhören"* and only found *"aufhören"*. I'd like to know the difference between the two forms. Is that form related to the infinitive?

Comment: What does your grammar book tell you?

Comment: Or Wiktionary https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufzuh%C3%B6ren

Answer (score 4):

There are German verbs with a special feature, that does not exist in English and many other languages. It's called:

### trennbare Verben (separable verbs)

A separable verb is a verb that can be split into two separate words, and the extra bonus is, that those parts can merge again to one word, enclosing some interfixes, that otherwise would be a distinct word (»zu«) or a prefix (»ge«).

»Aufhören« (to stop) is such a verb:

> I werde mit dem Rauchen **aufhören**.
>   I will **stop** smoking.

This example was »Futur I« where you use the auxiliary verb »werden« plus the infinitive. So in this tense, you use the word as it is written in a dictionary.

But when you use a separable verb in present tense, it looks this way:

> Ich **höre** mit dem Rauchen **auf**.
>   I **stop** smoking.

See? The word was split into its parts, and the former prefix moved to the very end of the sentence. This also can be true for longer sentences:

> Ich **höre**, wie ich dir bei deiner Geburtstagsfeier, bei der auch Tante Agnes und Onkel Hannes waren, versprochen habe, hier und heute mit dem Rauchen **auf**.

Past tense is build using an auxiliary verb (a form of *haben* or *sein*) plus a form of the verb that is built by adding the prefix »ge«:

> Ich schlafe. Ich fahre.
>   Ich habe **ge**schafen. Ich bin **ge**fahren.

If the verb is a separable verb, you do it this way:

> Ich habe mit dem Rauchen *auf**ge**hört*.
>   I stopped smoking.

Did you see how the syllable »ge« now squishes in between the two parts of the separable word? It's not a prefix here, it's an interfix.

And now comes the magic thing: zu + Infinitive. If you use non-separable verbs, then »zu« is a word and the infinitive is another word:

> Ich habe Lust **zu schlafen**.
>   I'd like to sleep.

And this is what happens with separable verbs:

> Ich habe Lust mit dem Rauchen *auf**zu**hören*.
>   I'd like to stop smoking.

So when ever you find »zu« or »ge« as second syllable in a verb, take this as a very strong hint that you are looking at a separable verb. Delete this interfix, and you get the infinitive that can be found in a dictionary.

Comment: Great explanation! Little german children sometimes get this wrong, which sounds very cute: "Ich bin ge-aufwacht."